# download file with HttpWebRequest

Tags: asp.net, httpwebrequest

how can download pdf file with HttpWebRequest?
i want download pdf file and save it to my system 
i can not download with WebClient because i need add cookie to my request

```
<code>
    Encoding encode = System.Text.Encoding.GetEncoding("utf-8");
    HttpWebRequest Request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(Url);
    CookieContainer cookieJar = new CookieContainer();
    cookieJar.Add(new Cookie("cookieName", "value", "/", "domain));      
    (Request as HttpWebRequest).CookieContainer = cookieJar;
     HttpWebResponse Response = (HttpWebResponse)Request.GetResponse();


</code>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use HttpWebRequest [GetResponseStream()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebresponse.getresponsestream.aspx) to get the body of the response as a stream, then save it to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:-

```
string GetPage(string path) {
 HttpWebRequest req = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(path);
req.CookieContainer = cookie;
WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
string t = new StreamReader(resp.GetResponseStream(), Encoding.Default).ReadToEnd();
return IsoToWin1250(t);
}
```